# Compression over HTTP/2 grpc

Tags: grpc, http2, armeria

We have a payload of 4MB to be returned to the client. We compress it to 500KB using gzip.
Without compression, calculating the response and receiving it at the client end in the application, overall it takes 200ms.
With compression, calculating the response and receiving it at the client end in the application, takes 190ms.
The server spends 1 ms in the compression process, while the client spends 20 ms in decompression process.
Even with a smaller data size, why would it take ~ a similar time over the wire for the data?

Edit: both client and server are implemented in kotlin.

Comment: In terms of the implementation principle of gzip,the  compress will consume more time than decompress.You may consider the different between your server and you client,such as : the programming language,the implement of gzip,etc.

Comment: The normal culprits: most of the time is spent in calculating the response, or in round-trip latency between the client and server.

Comment: Answering your question might be easier if you posted the breakdown of time spent as explained in this blog post: https://netbeez.net/blog/http-transaction-timing-breakdown-with-curl/ this way you'd know exactly how much time is spent in the network transfer.